# Negative margin jquery

Tags: jquery, margin

I'm writing an animation menu on the [site](http://funny.sem-dev.co.ua/)

When you hover over the first or third menu item, additional text appears between the text.
Now I hide it with a negative margin, and with the `:hover` I give him a `margin: 0`

There is a problem at iPhone
The first paragraph has two words in the additional text. On iPhone not correctly considers the indent and the text rides on each other.

Below is a script that counts and sets the right margin

```
$(function (){

    $('.multi-link span').each(function(){
        var w = $(this).width();
        $(this).css({
            'margin-right': w*(-1)
        });
    });

});

<li>
    <a class="header__menu-link multi-link" href="#">
        о <span>яркие впечатления</span> нас
    </a>
</li>
```

How to solve a similar problem? Thank you!

Comment: should be `'margin-right': w*(-1)+'px'`

Comment: `.css('margin-right': (w*-1)+'px')`